# How to move points in a polygons when editing/adjusting the polygon

Tags: qgis, editing, topology

I am using QGIS 2.14.3 and I am editing a few polygons in a layer, however in another layer I have some points (one or two points overlapping each polygon). Is there a way to move the points automatically when editing the polygon? I tried to use the snapping option by setting topological editing to enabled but it did not work for me.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. You can't move the points if you are not editing the points layer. Do you mean that you actually want to move a point to another location, or do you want to move edit a polygon in a way that cancel the overlap?

Comment: I would like to move/adjust the polygons and make the points move with them accordingly.

Comment: In arcgis something like this can be done by using spatial adjustment. There were some qgis plugins that attempted such tasks, but I didn't use them. Have a look on Vector Bender in Qgis plugins

Comment: I do not have access to AG, I have used the Spatial adjustment. I am looking for something more related to topology editing.